# Graphql & Relay production cases

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, relay, graphql-js

I'm thinking about using graphql/relay solution for my app, and I wonder which companies are using graphql/relay in production (except facebook).
Can you list here companies that uses it and their case studies.

Thanks.

Comment: GraphQL/Relay use does not necessarily imply redux use. That might be an unrelated tag, if you're only interested in GraphQL/Relay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relay maintains a list of companies that are using it in production in the GitHub repo:

https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/USERS.md

Comment: That's all? It only 5 companies

Comment: It's quite new. The technical preview was released in August 2015, and since it's built on top of two other new technologies (React and GraphQL), it might take some time before it gets integrated. As more people move to React and GraphQL though, Relay usage will grow.

Answer (score 0):

[Moderated list](https://github.com/graphql/graphql.github.io/blob/source/site/users/index.html.js) on Facebook repo(the accept pool requests  from companies that want to highlight their usage of GraphQL)

And [Users Page](http://graphql.org/users/)